# how to get SQL agent job name from a given SSIS package name?

Tags: ssis, sql-agent-job

I have package named "PROCESS_REPORT_SUBSCRIPTION_WEEKLY" . I need to list all the SQL agent jobs running this package.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the msdb database objects.

```
select 
     a.job_id JobID
    ,a.name JobName
    ,js.step_id
    ,js.step_name
    ,js.subsystem
    ,b.name SSISPackageName
    ,js.command
 from  msdb.dbo.sysjobs  a 
Left Join msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps js on js.job_id=a.job_id 
left join msdb.dbo.sysssispackages b on a.name=b.name
Where b.name like '%MySSISPackageName%' OR js.command  like '%MySSISPackageName%'
```

Note:

```
...OR js.command  like '%MySSISPackageName%'
```

This code is to handle if package is executed with in T-SQL syntax.

Comment: How are your package deployed? Location?

Comment: left join msdb.dbo.sysssispackages b on a.name=b.name does not work. Because we did not maintain consistency in names.